# Inkscape ready made grid

Tags: layout, grid, inkscape

I have been able to make a grid template on Inkscape so a default grid appears when you click New on file. Is it possible to be able to make a grid setting so that it could appear on files that have been edited but not new so they don't have to be drawn out everytime?

Answer (score 0):

If those files do not have a grid yet, then they will use the default grid that you can set at Edit > Preferences > User interface > Grids as soon as you turn on grid display.